# Problem writing a rigorous answer to a problem with little information

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble with a problem I have been given, I understand it conceptually but I can't seem to find a way to answer it rigorously because I don't have much information (almost none) about the function itself.

suppose f is a function on $(a, b)$ and that $f'(c) > 0$ for some $c$, $a < c < b$. Prove that there exists an $x$, $c < x < b$, such that $f(x) > f(c)$.

I understand there has to be a point $x$ that has a larger $f(x)$ than a point $c$ with a positive derivative. I just am having trouble finding a theorem / definition that works because I don't know anything about the function itself, such as if it is continuous or differentiable, etc. All I think I can surmise is that is on an open interval. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, differentiable implies continuous, so you have it's continuous AT c at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of derivative,
$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}>0.$$
Particularly:
$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}>0.$$
But if  $f(x) \le f(c)$ for all $x>c$:
$$\forall x>c:\qquad\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\frac-+\le 0$$
and
$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\le 0.$$

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you can trust the person who gave you the problem, having less information about the function is actually a **benefit**, because you don't need to try any possible approaches that would require more information than you have.
You only know that the derivative exists at the one point $c$ (and is positive there).  You don't know anything about continuity, or differentiability anywhere else, so you can forget about such results as the Mean Value Theorem or Intermediate Value Theorem.  What do you know about a function that is differentiable at one point $c$?  The definition of derivative, and not much else.
So use that...

Comment: This is kind of obvious, and I feel a little silly not thinking of it... I guess I was just overthinking the problem. Thanks!